# How to disable annoying mRemoteNG connection lost popups?

Tags: putty, mremoteng

How do I get rid of the annoying mRemoteNG lost connection popups that happen whenever an SSH session times out?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The popups actually come from PuttyNG. You need to change the putty options under tools->options->advanced. Relevant options are setting Session->"Close window on exit" to Always, enabling Connection->"Enable TCP keepalives" and setting Connection->"Seconds between keepalives" to more than 0.

Remember to save the PuttyNG settings as "Default Settings" in Session->"Saved Sessions".

Comment: lifesaver + timesaver